# I am not getting date range in proper format while passing date on page load. i am using ngx-daterangepicker-material plugin

Tags: angular

I am not getting date range in proper format while passing date on page load. i am using ngx-daterangepicker-material
plugin .this is what i am getting
`2019-03-01T00:00:00+05:30` To `2019-03-22T23:59:59+05:30`
this is my expectation
`03/01/2019` To `03/22/2019`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input  type="text"  matInput class="form-control form-control-sm bg_white" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" readonly
                            ngxDaterangepickerMd 
                            formControlName="DateRange" 
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.DateRange.errors }" 
                            [locale]="{applyLabel: '', cancelLabel: '',format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',separator: ' To ', firstDay: 1}"
                            [showRangeLabelOnInput]="showRangeLabelOnInput" 
                            startKey="start"
                            endKey="end"
                            [autoApply]="true"
                            [ranges]= "ranges"
                            [alwaysShowCalendars]="true"
                            [maxDate]= "maxDate"
                            [linkedCalendars]= "false" 
                            name="daterange"/>
```

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        let d1 = new Date("Fri Mar 17 2019");
        let d2 = new Date("Fri Mar 25 2019");
        this.dateSubmit.setValue({
            DateRange: { start: d1, end: d2 }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass the start and end date  in **ngAfterViewInit** and it will start working.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        let d1 = new Date("Fri Mar 17 2019");
        let d2 = new Date("Fri Mar 25 2019");
        this.dateSubmit.setValue({
            DateRange: { start: d1, end: d2 }
        });

    }
```